# use an int Variable for range to get random number

Tags: random

I am still fairly new to java. I want to make a game with 3 character types that have different stats. I am using int values for each type so that their attack value is a range instead of just being a constant value. Since each character has a different range, I want to substitute an int value instead of an actual number for the method to get a random number. Here is my code.

```
package battleme;

import java.util.Random;

/**
*
* @author Kitten
*/
class Character {


 String name;
int life;
int playerAttacklow;
int playerAttackhigh;
int playerDefense;
int playerLevel;
int currentXP;
int currentGold;



   public Character(String name, int life, int playerAttacklow, 
        int playerAttachhigh, int playerDefense, 
        int playerLevel, int currentXP, int currentGold) {
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getLife() {
    return life;
}

public void setLife(int life) {
    this.life = life;
}

public int getPlayerAttacklow() {
    return playerAttacklow;
}

public void setPlayerAttacklow(int playerAttacklow) {
    this.playerAttacklow = playerAttacklow;
}

public int getPlayerAttackhigh() {
    return playerAttackhigh;
}

public  void setPlayerAttackhigh(int playerAttackhigh) {
    this.playerAttackhigh = playerAttackhigh;
}

public int getPlayerDefense() {
    return playerDefense;
}

public void setPlayerDefense(int playerDefense) {
    this.playerDefense = playerDefense;
}

public int getPlayerLevel() {
    return playerLevel;
}

public void setPlayerLevel(int playerLevel) {
    this.playerLevel = playerLevel;
}

public int getCurrentXP() {
    return currentXP;
}

public void setCurrentXP(int currentXP) {
    this.currentXP = currentXP;
}

public int getCurrentGold() {
    return currentGold;
}

public void setCurrentGold(int currentGold) {
 this.currentGold = currentGold;
}
//the problem child
int ActualAttackGen(int playerAttackhigh, int playerAttacklow) {
    Random rn = new Random();
    int randomNum;

    randomNum= rn.nextInt((playerAttackhigh-playerAttacklow) + 1)+ playerAttacklow ;


            return randomNum ;
}

package battleme;



public class BattleMe {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
   Character Warrior = new Character("Warrior", 30, 2, 10, 3, 1, 1, 15);
   Character Rouge = new Character("Rouge", 25, 3, 6, 2, 1, 1, 15);
   Character Mage = new Character("Mage", 18, 2, 8, 1, 1, 1, 15);        

   // trying to run the problem child
   System.out.println(Warrior.ActualAttackGen(Warrior.playerAttackhigh,Warrior.playerAttacklow));


}

}
```

Whenever I try to run this, I always get an value of 0. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor you have to assign the passed values to the respective member of your Character class:

```
public Character(String name, int life, int playerAttacklow, 
    int playerAttachhigh, int playerDefense, 
    int playerLevel, int currentXP, int currentGold) {
    this.name = name;
    ....
}
```

BTW: It would be good coding practice to distinguish member and parameter names. Usually one prefixes one of them (or both). E.g. member myName, parameter aName. So you do not have to reference the member with "this.":

```
myName = aName;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I sincerely appreciate it :)

Comment: So please also vote up my answer and accept it as valid.